# Python not recognizing text from table cell using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my Python program... the last statement doesn't get printed, it leaves and empty line instead. Here's my program:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

print('Automated login for MDPI80X03 Started!')

driver=webdriver.Chrome() 
print('Chrome launched!')
driver.get(url)
print('Login successful!')

print('Timetable Loaded!')

print(driver.find_element_by_id('caccp1_header_clblHeader1').text)

print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="caccp1_content_clblContent1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text)
```

And the output i'm getting is:

> Automated login for MDPI80X03 Started!
>
> Chrome launched!
>
> Login successful!
>
> Timetable Loaded!
>
> Wednesday, March 6, 2019

Click here: [Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUusm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to extract is hidden, one of it ancestors has attribute `style="display: block; height: auto; overflow: hidden;"`. To get the text you need to use JavaScript command

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="caccp1_content_clblContent1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML', element))
```